# To find a Coordinate Patch About a Point in Euclidean Subspace.

Tags: continuity, manifolds

I have been trying to settle this question for a long time now and it is very important for me to solve this.

Let $p, q\in \mathbb R^2$ be points such that $p$ and $q$ are linearly independent (when considered as vectors in $\mathbb R^2$).

For any given $\theta$, write $$R_{\theta}=\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix}$$.

Let $M\subseteq (\mathbb R^2)^3$ be defined as $M=\{(x,x+R_\theta(p),x+ R_\theta(q)):x\in\mathbb R^2, \theta\in \mathbb R\}$.

I need to show that $M$ is a $3$-manifold in $\mathbb R^6$.

So should be able to find a coordinate patch about $(0,p,q)$ on $M$.

I think the function $\alpha: \mathbb R^2\times (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to M$ defined as $\alpha(x,\theta)=(x,x+R_\theta(p), x+ R_\theta(q))$ is a coordinate patch for sufficiently small (and positive) $\epsilon$.

I can show that $\alpha$ is bijective and has a constant rank 3 for sufficiently small and positive $\epsilon$.

But I am not able to show that $\alpha^{-1}$ is continuous, that is, $\alpha(G)$ is open in $M$ whenever $G$ is open in $\mathbb R^2\times (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$.

Can anybody see how to do that, or else, find some other coordinate patch about $(0,p,q)$ on $M$.

Thanks.

Comment: Pick a small compact set with non-empty interior $K$ around $x$ and $\epsilon_1 < \epsilon$.  Restricting $\alpha$ to the compact set $K\times [-\epsilon_1, \epsilon_1]$ will be bijective onto its image and constant rank $3$ since $\alpha$ is.  But since $K\times [-\epsilon_1 ,\epsilon_1]$ is compact, $\alpha$ is a closed map when restricted to it, hence $\alpha^{-1}$ is continuous when properly restricted.  Now, just find an even smaller open subset of $K\times [-\epsilon_1,\epsilon_1]$ and restrict further to get your patch.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thanks for your reply. Say $K=[a_1,b_1]\times [c_1,d_1]$. Also say $M_1$ is the image of $C_1=K\times [-\epsilon_1,\epsilon_1]$ under $\alpha$ and write $\alpha_1=\alpha|_{C_1}$. You have shown that $\alpha_1:C_1\to M_1$ has a continuous inverse. Let $G=(a_1,b_1)\times(c_1,d_1)\times (-\epsilon_1,\epsilon_1)$. I believe you want me to show that $\beta=\alpha|_G$ is a coordinate patch about $(o,p,q)$ on $M$. So I should be able to show that $\beta(G)$ is open in $M$. I know, from your help, that $\beta(G)$ is open in $M_1$. But I can't show $\beta(G)$ open in $M$. Can you explain?

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I had to run to class.  Showing that $\alpha|_G$ is open is equivalent to showing that it is closed because its bijective.  So, let $F\subseteq G$ be closed.  Since $F\subseteq G\subseteq C_1$ and $C_1$ is compact, $F$ is compact, and hence, so is $\alpha|_G(F)$.  This implies that $\alpha|_G(F)$ is closed in whatever space its in (provided the space is Hausdorff, which you get for free.)

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thanks again. Sorry for being stupid but I still don't fully get it. My temporary target is to show that $\alpha(G)$ is open in $M$ (If I can do that I can do the rest). I'll use your inputs given above and try to give proof of my temporary target. Let $L=C_1\setminus G$. Now $L$ is closed in $C_1$ and hence a compact space (since $C_1$ is compact). Thus $\alpha(L)$ is compact and hence closed in $M$(since $M$ is obviously Hausdorff). And I get stuck here. To keep fighting I know also that $\alpha(L)$ is closed in $M_1$ too and this gives me (continuied...)

Comment: (... continued)  that $\alpha(G)=M_1\setminus \alpha(L)$ is open in $M_1$. Which doesn't solve my problem. Can you please try to explain it to me again why $\alpha(G)$ is open in $M$? Thanks.

Comment: I see this issue now - this is a lot more subtle than I was thinking.  I'll keep thinking about it and get back to you.

Comment: I haven't been able to make my earlier suggestion work.  Now, as a substitute, I offer the constant rank theorem http://www.iecn.u-nancy.fr/~gaillapy/DIVERS/Constant-rank-theorem/constant-rank-theorem-110320a.pdf.  In short, up to a change of coordinates, you may locally assume your map $\alpha$ has the form $\alpha(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (x_1, x_2, x_3,0,0,0)$, from which, proving what you want is straightforward (unless I've, again, looked over some details!)  At this point, it's probably easier to ditch the machinery and just prove it by bare hands.

Comment: Related:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542300/constant-rank-map-means-image-locally-a-graph

Comment: Thank you for the new solution. All this is new to me so give me some time to study them. I'll get back with more doubts I am sure. :)

Comment: Okay. I have looked at the Constant Rank Theorem and I am still not sure how to go find a coordinate patch from there. Let's start again and define $\alpha:\mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R\to M$ as $\alpha(x,\theta)=(x,x+R_\theta(p).x+R_\theta(q))$. Now since $\alpha$ is smooth and has constant rank $3$, there exist open sets $U_1,U_2\subseteq \mathbb R^3$ and $U_3\subseteq \mathbb R^6$ with smooth diffeos $\phi:U_1\to U_2$ and $\psi: U_3\to U_3$ such that $(\psi\circ\alpha\circ\phi^{-1})(y)=(y_1,y_2,y_3,0,0,0)$ for all $y\in U_2$. Now I am not sure what can we have as our coordinate patch here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been difficult enough that I should just post a full solution at this point ;-).

The goal is to show that $\alpha:\mathbb{R}^2\times (\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow M$, when restricted to a suitable open subset, is an open map.  You have already shown that $\alpha$, when restricted to a suitable open subset is continuous, and bijective onto its image, and of constant rank 3.  To that end, let $V$ be any open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2\times (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$.  Our goal is to show that $\alpha(V)$ is open in $M$.  Note that do this, it's enough to show that for any $p\in V$, there is an open set $U$ with $p\in U\subseteq V$ and $\alpha(U)$ open in $M$.  So, fix a $p\in V$.

Using the constant rank theorem applied to $\alpha:\mathbb{R}^2\times (-\epsilon, \epsilon)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^6$ and the point $p$, we get open subsets $U_1,U_2\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2\times (\epsilon,\epsilon)$ with $p\in U_1$, an open subset $U_3\subseteq \mathbb{R}^6$, and diffeomorphisms $\phi:U_1\rightarrow U_2$ and $\psi:U_3\rightarrow U_3$ for which $(\psi \circ \alpha \circ \phi^{-1})(y) = (y_1,y_2,y_3,0,0,0)$.  Since $p\in U_1\cap V$, we may, by shrinking $U_1$ and $U_2$, assume wlog that $U_1\subseteq V$.  We will show that $\alpha(U_1)$ is open in $M$.

Now we know that $\psi(\alpha(U_1)) = \psi(\alpha(\phi^{-1}(U_2)) =  U_2\times \{(0,0,0)\}\subseteq U_3$.  Let $W = U_2\times (-\epsilon_1,\epsilon_1)^3$ where $\epsilon_1$ is chosen small enough that $W\subseteq U_3$.  Note that $W$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^6$.

Finally, I claim that $\psi^{-1}(W)\cap M = \alpha(U_1)$.  Since $\psi$ is continuous, $\psi^{-1}(W)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^6$, so $\alpha(U_1)$ is open in $M$.

Comment: Thank you so much. It looks right to me. Our whole discussion helped me a lot. I also got to know about the constant rank theorem. Really helpful. :)

Comment: :-).  Well, it took me enough tries to hammer out the details.  I learned a lot as well!

Comment: Can you please consider this related question. Let $p_1,\ldots,p_m\in \mathbb R^n$. Consider the set $M=\{(x,x+R(p_1),x+R(p_2),\ldots,x+R(p_m)): x\in\mathbb R^n, R\in O(n,\mathbb R)\}$. Then $M$ happens to be a manifold in $(\mathbb R^n)^m$. Do you see how we can find coordinate patches in this generalized situation?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have much time to think about it, at least for a while, but my first guess is that your above map suitably modified will work.  Namely, change the $(\epsilon, \epsilon)$, thought of as a small subset of $\mathbb{R} = Lie(S^1)$ to a small open subset of $o(n,\mathbb{R}) = Lie(O(n,\mathbb{R})$.  At least when $m = n$, this should work.

Comment: Thank you. Guess it's time to start reading lie theory after all.

Answer (score 2):

(I address the question of showing $M$ is a manifold) By a linear change of coordinates, you may as well assume $p,q$ are the standard basis vectors $e_1, e_2$.

Then $M$ is given as set $(x, x + (\cos \theta, \sin \theta), x + (-\sin \theta, \cos \theta))$. Applying the diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^6$ given by $(v, w, z) \mapsto (v, w - v, z - v)$ (with inverse $(v, w, z) \mapsto (v, w + v, z + v)$), it now looks like $$(x, (\cos \theta, \sin \theta), (-\sin \theta, \cos \theta) ) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^6$$I leave as an exercise the details of showing this is $\cong \mathbb{R}^2 \times S^1$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Let me study your answer (I am new to these things) and come back.